# Reference request for result on irreducible polynomials with roots in every non-Archimedean completion

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

My question concerns the following result:

**Theorem**. *Let $K$ be an algebraic number field. If $f(x) \in K[x]$ is irreducible over $K$ and has a root in every non-Archimedean completion of $K$, then $f$ is linear.*

This appears to be a well-known result - a proof for $K = \mathbb{Q}$ can be found in answer to a question of mine here: [The Hasse principle for bivariate cubic forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3966191/the-hasse-principle-for-bivariate-cubic-forms/3966280#3966280)
The proof crucially relies on the Chebotarev density theorem.

I have been trying to find a textbook reference for this proof, but have been unable to find one. Its corollary that an element in $K^{\times}$ is a square in $K$ if and only if it is a square in every non-Archimedean completion of $K$, is equivalent to the Hasse-Minkowski theorem for binary quadratic forms over all algebraic number fields (similarly for cubes in $K$ and the binary cubic analogy of the Hasse-Minkowski theorem). The trouble is that all the proofs of the Hasse-Minkowski theorem over all algebraic number fields that I have been able to find do not prove this result - Hasse's original paper makes reference to a related result in a paper by Hilbert (which I find unreadable), T.Y. Lam's book simply assumes the result without reference, and O'Meara proves the theorem by different means.

So my question to the community is: Is anyone aware of the existence of a textbook or published paper where the above result is proved?

Many thanks.

Comment: You might try asking this question in a comment on the linked answer, or linking to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered the OP's question at the MO link he includes, but for completeness (in case someone else comes across this page) I'll give an answer here too: the theorem appears as a corollary on p. 170 of the second edition (not the first edition) of Lang's *Algebraic Number Theory*.

It also appears as Exercise 6.2 at the end of Cassels and Froehlich's *Algebraic Number Theory* and Exercise 5 in Chapter IV of the second edition of Janusz's *Algebraic Number Fields* (with a small error: Janusz's exercise is that for a monic irreducible polynomial in $\mathbf Z[x]$ of "arbitrary degree" there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that the polynomial has no root in $\mathbf Z/(p)$, so he clearly forgot to include the assumption that the polynomial has degree greater than $1$).  The exercise in Janusz also appears as Theorem $1$ on the first page of Serre's paper [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2003-40-04/S0273-0979-03-00992-3/S0273-0979-03-00992-3.pdf), where Serre correctly includes the condition that the degree of the polynomial is at least $2$.